# Xcode 6 beta iPad simulator portrait no split view on launch

Tags: xcode, ipad, simulator, launch

In iPad i am using split view controller (one of my existing apps).  Using Xcode 6 beta: If I launch the iPad simulator(s) with the device in portrait orientation it only shows the detail view and not the master view as well (and no "master" back button). If I rotate then to landscape all appears fine, rotate back to portrait and the "master"back button appears and can then access the master table view. With previous versions of Xcode the split view launches in portrait view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also noticed this, it seems to be a bug in Xcode 6 and iOS Simulator 8. You can send a bug report to Apple [here](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: Don't think it is bug of simulator. It is the same for real device (no button when launched in portrait).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when running my app on the iOS8 simulator using xCode6-beta2.  However, when I ran the app on my iOS7 device, the master view title showed up correctly.  Sounds like an iOS8 issue.